# Which event should be used to update a Model from TextBox (LostFocus, LostKeyboardFocus, etc) in WPF? How to set precedence of events in WPF?

Tags: wpf, events, textbox, updatemodel, lostfocus

I have an application in which there are lot of TextBoxes and some Buttons like Save, SaveAs,etc. 
When the user edits a TextBox, I have to check the DataBase for some range, validate the range and update the DataBase. 
If there is any error in value entered by user,then I should not allow the TextBox to lose focus.

**I was using LostFocus event** for this and it was working fine until lately I discovered a bug in my application.

**Bug :** The user edits a value in TextBox and then clicks on Save button; the LostFocus event is not called and so Database is not getting updated :(

Now my question is which event should I use in TextBox to update the DataBase. I tried TextChanged event but it validates for every character and making my application slow. I am confused in chosing the right event for this kind of application!

**Note** :** The Buttons are in different UserControl !

**EDIT 1 :** I have some Commands attached to click of Buttons, these Commands are getting executed before LostFocus !! Can I set precedence or something like attached behaviours or commands should get executed after LostFocus !!

**EDIT 2 :** I was just debugging the application by disabling some commands, what I found was in some cases, the DelegateCommand gets executed before LostFocus, so I want to avoid that. How can I go about it ? I felt during development its impossible to developa pure MVVM application so I am kind of using a bit of codebehind !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trapping the keyboard focus within a control is usually a sign of bad UI design - it's pretty user-hostile to force the user to fix data in a control before he can type anywhere else in the UI.

That said, you shouldn't be using events at all here.  You're trying to write a Windows Forms application in WPF.  You should write a WPF application.

Create a class that is a logical model of your view - i.e., there's a `string` property for the text box and a `Command` property (or, more likely, a `RelayCommand`) for the Save button.  Bind the text box to the string property, e.g.:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Because the `UpdateSourceTrigger` is `PropertyChanged`, the source object will get updated every time the user types a character.

Bind the button to the command property, e.g.:

```
<Button CommandBinding="{Binding SaveCommand}">Save</Button>
```

Implement the appropriate `CanSave` and `Save` methods that the `RelayCommand` (as described in [Josh Smith's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) essential article on the MVVM pattern) requires, so that the button is enabled when the string property is valid and disabled when it's not.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is preventing a user to proceed until all valid information has been gathered.

Just like an installation wizard with `Terms & Conditions Dialog` and `Next` button. Until you check the `I Agree` checkbox, `Next` button is disabled.

This way, you don't have to worry about user proceeding without providing valid information. This way, you can use any event on `TextBox` to validate your data.

Comment: @Decyclone - When do I do the validation of value in TextBox? Is it in LostFocus, textChanged, etc ?

Comment: @GuruC - I think, by default its `LostFocus`.

Comment: @Decyclone - Yes but it is not getting fired when I click on some Buttons in usercontrol!

Comment: That is what I was trying to say in my answer. Disable these buttons until all your data is valid.

Comment: @Decyclone - Ok lets say what u said works for InvalidData. Now the user enters a valid data and he doesnot press tab, he clicks on save button. Lost focus is not called so new value is not updated to database. Am I making my point clear ?